# How does the code below work? It outputs the number broken up and it is fully functioning, I just don't understand how it does it

Tags: c++, modulus

I dont understand how the code below functions. It successfully outputs the broken up number but i want to comprehend how it functions. Can someone please explain?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int number; //declares variable number
    int n1,n2,n3,n4; //declares four integer variables
    cout << "Please enter a four digit number:"; //outputs message
    cin >> number;

    n1 = number%10;  /* the next eight lines are what i am having trouble understanding */
    number /= 10;
    n2 = number%10;
    number /= 10;
    n3 = number%10;
    number /= 10;
    n4 = number%10;
    number /=10;

    cout << "ones:" << n1 << endl;
    cout << "tens:" << n2 << endl;
    cout << "hundreds:" << n3 << endl;
    cout << "thousands:" << n4 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is not fit for this forum: you seek in depth explanation about a code fragment (which is quite self-explanatory). I'd suggest you reading about the modulus and basic operations. HINT:  '/=' is just like '+=' -> meaning that the number variable will be updated. Just like doing number = number / 10;

Answer (score 1):

Ok so `n1 = number % 10` gives you remainder of division by ten. (If input is 2137 then its 7). After that `number/=10` means the same as `number = number/10` so number after that will be 213 (because total division takes place) and next lines are basicly the same

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by saying that StackOverflow is not really made for questions that are in the form of "Please explain this chunk of code for me". However, I'll still go through it for you since you are new to StackOverflow, but keep this in mind when writing your next question :)

## TL;DR

`number%10` extracts the last digit of the number.

`number /= 10` divides the number by 10, removes the decimal part, and stores the answer in `number`.

## Long explanation

#### Remainders

Here, you are using the **modulo operation**, or `%`. This operation divides the numbers, but instead of outputting the answer, it returns the **remainder**.

Here is a way of understanding remainders. Say we do `3/2`, and floor the returned value (remove the decimal part):

```
3/2 = 1.5
floor(1.5) = 1
```

Now, lets do the inverse of the division (multiply the divisor by our answer):

```
3/2 = 1.5
1.5 * 2 = 3
```

If we multiply the divisor with our floored answer instead:

```
1 * 2 = 2    ----> This is not 3
```

To calculate the remainder, we find the difference between this "wrong" answer and the "correct" answer:

```
(correct answer) - (wrong answer) = remainder
3 - 2 = 1
remainder = 1
```

So, using our fancy `%` syntax that *returns* the *remainder*:

```
3%2 = 1
```

Here is another example:

```
17/3 = 5.666
floor(5.666) = 5

Inverse of division (multiply divisor by our answer):
5.666 * 3 = 17     ----> 17 is our "correct" value

Inverse of division, by with our floored value:
5 * 3 = 15   ----> 15 is our "wrong" value

Difference between our "correct" and "wrong" values:
17 - 15 = 2

So:
17%3 = 2
```

#### In your code...

How does you code use this?
Say the number you input is `4559`.

```
n1 = number%10 becomes:
n1 = 4559%10
```

If we follow the trick we used earlier,

```
4559/10 = 455.9
floor(455.9) = 455

455.9 * 10 = 4559   ----> Correct answer
455 * 10 = 4550     ----> Wrong answer

4559 - 4550 = 9     ----> Remainder

So:
4559%10 = 9
```

In short, `number%10` extracts the last digit of `number`.

#### The `/= 10`

There is a little other trick used in your code.

```
number /= 10
```

Here, you are simply diving you original number by 10. However, `number` is declared as an `int`, or integer. Integers cannot have any decimal parts. Because of this, the computer simply gets rid of the decimal part after the division (it essentially *floors* the value).
In our case, because `4559 / 10 = 455.9`, the computer gets rid of the `.9`:

```
4559 / 10 = 455    ----> This is what the computer returns
```

Finally, you use `/=`, which simply means *do the division with `number`, and store the answer in  `number`*.
If we again use `4559`:

```
number /= 10
cout << number    ----> Outputs 455
```

In other words, `number /= 10` simply **removes** a digit from `number`.

```
int number = 4559

n1 = number%10     ----> n1 = 9
number /= 10       ----> number = 455
n2 = number%10     ----> n2 = 5
number /= 10       ----> number = 45
n3 = number%10     ----> n3 = 5
number /= 10       ----> number = 4
n4 = number%10     ----> n4 = 4
```